# RawPostDataException at * You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

Hi i am facing an issue whe i have migrated code from my local system to AWS

RawPostDataException at /users/
You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream

It seems i can't access request.method and request.data in views.py simulteneously.
Is this specific to AWS?Do i nedd to do some specific config changes to resolve this issue?

It would be great if you can suggest some work around for this issue

Comment: Here is the code that is failing
def sign_up_edit_and_list_users(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return HttpResponse(request.method+request.body)
    else :
        return HttpResponse("request.body")

Comment: This is the error
RawPostDataException at /users/
You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://54.169.169.192/users/
Django Version: 1.8.7
Exception Type: RawPostDataException
Exception Value: 
You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py in body, line 231
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:

Comment: ['/home/ubuntu/jb',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
Server time: Wed, 2 Dec 2015 15:18:11 +0000